# How to indicate a column as NULL in a SQL view?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, view

I have a question for you: can I create a view with NULLABLE column? And, if it's possibile, how can I define it?

At the moment, I tried to get this behaviour with the following statement

```
SELECT     ISNULL(aaa, ' ') AS aaa, 
FROM table
```

but when I import this view within my .NET Entity Framework, it takes all column as NOT NULL.

Have you got any suggestion??

Thanks in advance,

Deby

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you want to preserve `NULL` values in a view you odn't have to do anything other than include the fields with `NULL` values in your view.  In your current query you're turning `NULL` values in column aaa to a string with a space in it.

Comment: @Deby can you pls further explain your question

Comment: Mmmmh ... Maybe I was tring to use a view in a wrong way. In fact: given the entity "view" within the Entity Framework, I was tring to use it as a common class, using its field as TwoWay binded data...And it cannot work :( ...Thank you anyway, and sorry!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I test for nullability by creating tables using `select into`.  Here is an example:

```
select 'aaa' as col1,
       (case when 1=1 then 'aaa' end) as col2,
       cast('aaa' as varchar(255)) as col3
into t;
```

You can then check for `NULLABILITY` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 't';
```

In this case, the third option using the `cast()` produces a `NULLABLE` column.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the ISNULL statement from your view, when .net is in doubt it will make an imported column nullable.